# How to register a hibernate typedescriptor in a "classic" Spring 5 application with jpa entitymanager

Tags: spring, hibernate, registration, entitymanager, typedescriptor

I have a classic spring 5 application (NO spring boot). For a custom basic type i have created a typedescriptor by subclassing AbstractTypeDescriptor according to [Hibernate 5.2 Documentation - 2.3.5. Explicit BasicTypes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-type-annotation). I am using hibernate via an jpa entitymanager. I have two spring beans configured for that: a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and a HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.
Now i am a bit lost, how to register the typedescriptor during startup of the application. The docs mention an approach using a hibernate configuration object. But i have no idea, how to get this? Any help appreciated!

Comment: The Hibernate documentation you linked to says: "Alternatively, use can use a `@TypeDef` ans skip the registration phase:
Example 11. Using `@TypeDef` to register a custom Type"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That solved my problem. Still wondering, how i could get access to a hibernate configuration object, but just out of curiosity...